# Longtable Errors

Tags: tables, errors, longtable

When I complile my latex I'm getting all sorts of errors. No matter what I try and change in my code I get several different errors. I've been at this for about a week so I may need help to work this out. Hoping somebody can come help me clean up the table and help make it into a working example for the rest of my tables.

```
Runaway argument?
{\tablename \ \thetable \ -- \textit {Continued from previous page} \\\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn.
<inserted text>
            \par
l.21 \input{"KCMPlusUserGuideSource.tex"}
```

Here is the source text file:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<!--                        
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\caption{A simple longtable example}
\label{hello} \\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}% 
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
show            & true, false                                               & Whether or not to draw the series. \\ \hline
xaxis           & 'xaxis' or 'x2axis'                                       & Which x axis to use with this series. \\ \hline
yaxis           & 'yaxis' or 'y2axis'                                       & Which y axis to use with this series. \\ \hline
renderer        & \$.jqplot.BarRenderer, \$.jqplot.PieRenderer, \$.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer & A class of a renderer which will draw the series. \\ \hline
rendererOptions & {a,b,c...}                                                & Options to pass on to the renderer. \\ \hline
label           & 'label'                                                   & Line label to use in the legend. \\ \hline
showLabel       & true, false                                               & True to show label for this series in the legend. \\ \hline
color           &                                                           & CSS color spec for the series. \\ \hline
lineWidth       & n                                                         & Width of the line in pixels.  \\ \hline
lineJoin        & 'round'                                                   & Canvas lineJoin style between segments of series. \\ \hline
lineCap         & 'round'                                                   & Canvas lineCap style at ends of line. \\ \hline
shadow          & true, false                                               & Whether or not to draw a shadow on the line. \\ \hline
shadowAngle     & n                                                         & Shadow angle in degrees. \\ \hline
shadowOffset    & n                                                         & Shadow offset from line in pixels. \\ \hline
shadowDepth     & n                                                         & Number of times shadow is stroked, each stroke offset shadowOffset from the last. \\ \hline
shadowAlpha     & n                                                         & Alpha channel transparency of shadow.  0 = transparent. \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
-->
\end{document}
```

This is the pre-amble:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\newcommand{\titleinfo}{Default Title - should be overridden} 
\newcommand{\authorinfo}{The Kildrummy Corporation Limited} 
\newcommand{\releaseinfo}{Release 1.2}
\newcommand{\copyrightinfo}{Copyright \copyright \ \the\year \ The Kildrummy Corporation Limited}
\newcommand{\versioninfo}{Version: 0}

\title{\titleinfo} 
\author{\releaseinfo \\ \\ \authorinfo}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\oldsection\section 
\renewcommand{\section}{\clearpage\oldsection} 

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.2in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-5pt}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-27pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{20pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{5pt}

\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ptm}\normalfont\upshape
\renewcommand*\sfdefault{ptm}\normalfont\upshape
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{ptm}\normalfont\upshape

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\slshape \rightmark}

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize \titleinfo}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize \titleinfo}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\releaseinfo}]       {\fancyplain{}{\releaseinfo}}
\lfoot[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize \copyrightinfo}]{\fancyplain{}{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize \copyrightinfo}}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\rfoot[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please always post a complete document so people can run it and reproduce the problem. (putting longtable in `center` does nothing useful, although shouldn't make this error)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I add `\documentclass` etc to the file as posted it runs _without error_. The error message you show is on line 5, do you really have `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}` all on one line?

Comment: Replace `\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}` with `\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}`

Comment: after your edit the posted fragment can not be run at all. Please make examples _complete_ However you have introduced the missing brace that was not in the code you originally posted, which was error free.

Comment: You can not have `\usepackage` after `\begin{document}` is that really your source file? If so I would have expected several errors before you got to the longtable.

Comment: Right alot of comments and I'm not sure where to start. I have a "pre-amble" I think its called? I have almost no knowledge of latex so this is all pretty confusing. I am not sure how you guys are getting this to run but I still can't after adding these snippets. I am using multi-markdown if that helps

Comment: @PaulLewis the important thing is to post the document (in full) that you used to generate the error. Posting an error message and a fragment of a document that does not generate any error makes it hard to help. But I'll post an answer with a working version

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It can't be anything but something to do with the table, everything else works fine without this table.

Comment: Not with the documents that you are posting, the one above will give an error on line 1 for the `\usepackage` command. Before it gets anywhere near the start of the document. The error message you have above is not from the document that you have in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your document (after the last edit) has `\usepackage` and `\documentclass` in the wrong order and a spurious XML comment syntax `<!--` I do not think it made the error message that you posted, which is from a different document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\caption{A simple longtable example}
\label{hello} \\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}% 
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
show            & true, false                                               & Whether or not to draw the series. \\ \hline
xaxis           & 'xaxis' or 'x2axis'                                       & Which x axis to use with this series. \\ \hline
yaxis           & 'yaxis' or 'y2axis'                                       & Which y axis to use with this series. \\ \hline
renderer        & \$.jqplot.BarRenderer, \$.jqplot.PieRenderer, \$.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer & A class of a renderer which will draw the series. \\ \hline
rendererOptions & {a,b,c...}                                                & Options to pass on to the renderer. \\ \hline
label           & 'label'                                                   & Line label to use in the legend. \\ \hline
showLabel       & true, false                                               & True to show label for this series in the legend. \\ \hline
color           &                                                           & CSS color spec for the series. \\ \hline
lineWidth       & n                                                         & Width of the line in pixels.  \\ \hline
lineJoin        & 'round'                                                   & Canvas lineJoin style between segments of series. \\ \hline
lineCap         & 'round'                                                   & Canvas lineCap style at ends of line. \\ \hline
shadow          & true, false                                               & Whether or not to draw a shadow on the line. \\ \hline
shadowAngle     & n                                                         & Shadow angle in degrees. \\ \hline
shadowOffset    & n                                                         & Shadow offset from line in pixels. \\ \hline
shadowDepth     & n                                                         & Number of times shadow is stroked, each stroke offset shadowOffset from the last. \\ \hline
shadowAlpha     & n                                                         & Alpha channel transparency of shadow.  0 = transparent. \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This runs without error but `'xaxis'` is wrong as it makes two right  quotes, probably you want to use `\texttt{'xaxis'}` to use monospace and straight quotes.

Comment: This provides another error for me because \documentclass{article}, \usepackage{longtable} and \begin{document} are stated in the "pre-amble". If I take out the tables the document works fine. I am using multi markdown so it is just pure text, and then I needed a more complex table which multi markdown doesn't support.

Comment: @PaulLewis sorry but this is a latex forum, and the above is a complete error free latex document. If you have a markdown processor (I do not know that one) that is generating incorrect latex then really that is a question about that processor and is probably off topic here.

Comment: This is not only latex forum. This is TeX forum too :)